# Set Image With URL having authentication-IOS SDK

Tags: ios, web-services, authentication, uitableview, uiimageview

Hello i am trying to display images from url in tableview,the problem is that url is having authentication,how to display image url having authentication.Code i tried is given below.

```
 [cell.im setImageWithURL:[NSURL   
 URLWithString:@"https://bouxxxx.XXXxtech.net/api/images/products/426/690"] 
 placeholderImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"botton_orange_up 2.png"]];
```

Comment: Below is one Github library: https://github.com/nicklockwood/AsyncImageView That might help you

Comment: i also have have to pass certificate also to the request .any ideas....stuck for a while now...?

Answer (score 1):

first you send your username and password in your post method with api and then server authentication with you to get data from server and load image in tableview check out the apple source code its help you

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/LazyTableImages/

Comment: Thanks but my problem is just with authentication.the url given above uses an authentication key which i have with me to open normally,but how to give authentication to such a command.